# Linux device driver development: what does it look like in 2012?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-device-driver

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I *assume* that all the items I see listed when I run `ls /dev` are actually the device drivers for all the devices/hardware components connected to (or able to connect to) my machine. Is this correct? If not, where does Linux store all the device drivers?

What are drivers written in, C? C++? Assembler? What modern IDE/tech stack do device driver developers use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not correct. `/dev` is a folder full of special device files, which represent device drivers. So when I do something to `/dev/sda` I am not working with the file of the SATA driver, but rather an interface to whatever SATA driver happens to be loaded. Device files are how drivers expose their devices to userspace (along with system calls that call drivers).

Usually drivers are stored in `/lib/modules`.

Drivers are written in C, unless you want to tripple your workload and write in assembly. There isn't a single line of C++ in the entire Linux kernel, for technical and political reasons (Linus Torvalds hates the sight of it).

IDE? I doubt any kernel developers use IDEs. Most of them just use Vim or EMACS. Then git to commit to the kernel source, and GDB/KDB for debugging. And whatever other command line tools are needed (eg. `diff`).